# Gradle build error while using Android Studio 1.3.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm completely new to Android and I'm trying to build my first app. I'm using Lynda.com's exercise files to start with and every time I load a project I get these errors [image]
[image]
 Please help me fix these errors so I can move forward.

Also, my laptop has become very very very slow ever since I installed Android Studio, anyway I can speed it up again !!

Comment: "my laptop has become very very very slow ever since I installed Android Studio, anyway I can speed it up again": get a more powerfull working station -- IDEs consumes resources... The rest seems specific to an external website's tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I started developing Android recently too, and I had a problem with Gradle, just like you. So what I did is modify a little in `build.gradle(Module)` :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

And here

```
buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"
```

That's how it works for me.